# Need to pull large set of data from one database and insert into another

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to pull a large set of data from one database, rename the columns, then dump it into another. I started getting timeouts and upped the max_execution_time and max_input_time. This helped but I still was not getting all the data. I then added the following:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(1);
```

This doubled the amount of data I was able to pull but im still short so its still timing out. Im wondering if there is a better way to do this.

I am using Laravel 5.6,php 7.2 ,mysql 5.6

I am pulling from one database and inserting into another.

```
$availabilities = DB::connection('mysql2')->select('select vi.status as availability_status_code,vi.date as availability_date,v.masterid as im_id from table1 vi
inner join table2 v on v.id = vi.vid where vi.date >= CURDATE() and v.masterid > 0 order by v.masterid,vi.date'); //
foreach($availabilities as $availability) {
    Availabilities::create((array)$availability);
}
```

This works but as noted times out.

Is there a more efficient way to handle this or should I just increase different time limits until it works? Keep in mind this will run once or twice a day via a job.

Comment: Run it from PHP CLI there is no time limit on the CLI and afterall you only want to run this once right

Comment: You could add a LIMIT to the query and repeat as needed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
DB::table('yourtable')->insert([['name' => '1st record'], ['name => '2nd record']]);
```

Of course you should chunk this into parts, so you shouldn't insert this way for example 1 million of record, but you should break 1 million records into array of for example 200 records. It will be much faster than inserting each record separately as you do now.

You can use collection [chunk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-chunk) method to chunk your `$availabilities` into smaller parts

Comment: Hi Marcin I like this method and tried it but it came back with the error: Call to member chunk on array. One challenge has been since I am pulling this as raw mysql its returning it in some sort of json/array format. I dont think I can use the chunk method because of this.

Comment: @Scott Ah, okey, you are not using query builder here, so you can use native PHP function http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php to split array into multiple chunks

Answer (score 0):

If your database user has privileges to both the database and there are no processing involved between fetching the data from one source and adding to another, you can try doing this in a single query.

```
INSERT INTO database2.table_name (availability_status_code, availability_date, im_id)
SELECT vi.status AS availability_status_code, vi.date AS availability_date, v.masterid AS im_id 
FROM database1.table1 vi
    INNER JOIN database1.table2 v ON v.id = vi.vid 
WHERE vi.date >= CURDATE() AND v.masterid > 0
ORDER BY v.masterid,vi.date
```

You may also try this approach if there is some processing involved and that which can be done in MYSQL.

Comment: Sorry I am not good at laravel. So could not give laravel specific answer.

Comment: Hi Sheikh, this is how I would have wanted to do it but Im connecting to one database, pulling the data then inserting into another database. Two different connections so I cant ( I dont think ) do it this way. I can run raw mysql and php in laravel.

Comment: I guess you can do this from 1 connection if the same user has permissions in the other database table(s).